# Computing vertex normal in OpenGL ES2 shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having some issues with the lighting of an obj model I grabbed from Google Poly. In this model a bunch of faces are defined with no normals. As such, the calculation I'm using for the diffuse color is returning 0. Is there any way to estimate the normal if not provided or do I need to parse the obj and inject the normals manually?

Here's my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform bool u_UseTexAmbient;
uniform bool u_UseTexDiffuse;
uniform bool u_UseTexSpecular;

uniform sampler2D u_TexAmbient;
uniform sampler2D u_TexDiffuse;
uniform sampler2D u_TexSpecular;

uniform vec3 u_MtlAmbient;
uniform vec3 u_MtlDiffuse;
uniform vec3 u_MtlSpecular;

uniform float u_D;
uniform float u_SpecularPower;

uniform vec4 u_LightingParameters;

varying vec3 v_ViewPosition;
varying vec3 v_ViewNormal;
varying vec2 v_TexCoord;

vec4 getColor(bool useTex, sampler2D tex, vec3 mtl);
vec3 computeDiffuse(vec3 viewNormal, vec3 rawDiffuseColor);
vec3 computeSpecular(vec3 viewNormal, vec3 viewFragmentDirection, vec3 rawSpecularColor);

void main() {
    const float kGamma = 0.4545454;
    vec3 viewFragmentDirection = normalize(v_ViewPosition);
    vec3 viewNormal = normalize(v_ViewNormal);

    vec4 rawAmbientColor = getColor(u_UseTexAmbient, u_TexAmbient, u_MtlAmbient);
    vec4 rawDiffuseColor = getColor(u_UseTexDiffuse, u_TexDiffuse, u_MtlDiffuse);
    vec4 rawSpecularColor = getColor(u_UseTexSpecular, u_TexSpecular, u_MtlSpecular);

    vec3 diffuse = computeDiffuse(viewNormal, rawDiffuseColor.rgb);
    vec3 specular = computeSpecular(viewNormal, viewFragmentDirection, rawSpecularColor.rgb);

    gl_FragColor.a = rawDiffuseColor.a * u_D;
    gl_FragColor.rgb = pow(rawAmbientColor.rgb + diffuse + specular, vec3(kGamma));
}

vec4 getColor(bool useTex, sampler2D tex, vec3 mtl) {
    const float kInverseGamma = 2.2;
    vec4 color;
    if (useTex) {
        color = texture2D(tex, vec2(v_TexCoord.x, 1.0 - v_TexCoord.y));
    } else {
        color = vec4(mtl.r, mtl.g, mtl.b, 1.0);
    }
    color.rgb = pow(color.rgb, vec3(kInverseGamma));
    return color;
}

vec3 computeDiffuse(vec3 viewNormal, vec3 rawDiffuseColor) {
    vec3 diffuse = u_LightingParameters.w * rawDiffuseColor
            * max(dot(u_LightingParameters.xyz, viewNormal), 0.0);
    return clamp(diffuse, 0.0, 1.0);
}

vec3 computeSpecular(vec3 viewNormal, vec3 viewFragmentDirection, vec3 rawSpecularColor) {
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(u_LightingParameters.xyz, viewNormal);
    float specularStrength = max(0.0, dot(viewFragmentDirection, reflectedLightDirection));
    vec3 specular = u_LightingParameters.w * rawSpecularColor *
        pow(specularStrength, u_SpecularPower);
    return clamp(specular, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And this vertex shader taken from Google's ARCore example:

```
uniform mat4 u_ModelView;
uniform mat4 u_ModelViewProjection;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec3 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;

varying vec3 v_ViewPosition;
varying vec3 v_ViewNormal;
varying vec2 v_TexCoord;

void main() {
    v_ViewPosition = (u_ModelView * a_Position).xyz;
    v_ViewNormal = normalize((u_ModelView * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0)).xyz);
    v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;
    gl_Position = u_ModelViewProjection * a_Position;
}
```

Basically what I'm seeing is that some models can't provide me with `a_Normal`, so I'd like to be able to somehow generate `v_ViewNormal` without it in the vertex shader. Is this even possible?

Here's a link to the full model: https://poly.google.com/view/eydI4__jXpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility would be to calucalte the normal vector per fragment, in the fragment shader, by using the partial derivative functions [`dFdx`, `dFdy`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/)

Note, in OpenGL ES 2.0 the [`OES_standard_derivatives`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_standard_derivatives.txt) extension is rquired, because the derivative functions have only become standard since OpenGL ES 3.0.

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00 Specification; 8.9 Fragment Processing Functions; page 104](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf):

> `genType dFdx (genType p)`
>
> Returns the derivative in *x* using local differencing for the input argument `p`.
>
> `genType dFdy (genType p)`
>
> Returns the derivative in *y* using local differencing for the input argument `p`.

The code may look somehow like this:

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

varying vec3 view_pos;

void main
{
    vec3 dX     = dFdx(view_pos);
    vec3 dY     = dFdy(view_pos);
    vec3 normal = normalize(cross(dX, dY));

    ....
}
```

See further [An introduction to shader derivative functions - Face normal computation (flat shader)](http://www.aclockworkberry.com/shader-derivative-functions/#Face_normal_computation_flat_shader)